# How do I enable automatic history expansion for commands using 'magic space'?

Tags: command-line, bash, history

I read [on a blog somewhere](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/bash-history-expansion/#comment-4106) about the possibility to use automatic history expansion before actually executing a command or even pressing the enter key in the command line.
It involves the 'magic-space' and creating an `~/.inputrc` configuration file.

What should that file contain exactly and when is it read  (in login and non-login bash shells)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the blog command you just need:

```
$if Bash
  Space: magic-space
$endif
```

The rest (the default settings) are sitting in `/etc/inputrc`.

This is read when GNU Readline (the input library Bash uses) is started. Because it's not directly part of Bash, `reset` and `source ~/.bashrc` et al won't work. To reload this without starting a new session, you need to run  [`bind -f ~/.inputrc`](https://superuser.com/a/419676/30127).

Comment: Very nice indeed. It works very well and makes the ~/.bashrc shell option --  shopt -s histverify -- redundant. Thank you.

Comment: Great answer for additionally wrapping the binding in an `if` to protect other shells that use readline such as `PostgreSQL` and `SQLite`.